# UIWebView didFinishLoad not firing

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Im trying to logon to a gmail form, and then check the link to see whether he has logged in. Here is the code.

```
- (IBAction)loginToForm:(id)sender {
    NSString *zname= username.text;
    NSString *passwordEnter= password.text;
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByName('Email')[0].value = '%@';",zname]];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByName('Passwd')[0].value = '%@';",passwordEnter]];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByName('signIn')[0].click();"];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    NSString *returnData = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location"];
    NSLog(@"%@",returnData);
    if([returnData rangeOfString:@"ServiceLogin"].location != NSNotFound){
        success=YES;
        NSLog(@"YES"); 
    }else{
        NSLog(@"NO");
    }
}
```

However, the webViewDidFinishLoad does not fire. Any Help? Thanks Guys!

Comment: Have you set the delegate of the webview?

Comment: wow stupid mistake
sorry about that 
ur right

i didnt declare the [webView setDelegate:self] in viewDidLoad

works now thanks!

Comment: make it an answer and ill accept

Comment: actually now that part is figured out...the method i am using to check whether the user is logged in doesnt work
mind helping me?

Comment: What is the output of the returnData?

Comment: return data is simply the url of the webview